# How to get specifi list of Virtual Machine Status from Azure using powershell from Excel sheet

Tags: excel, powershell, azure-vm

I am pretty much new to PowerShell and we have customer requirement that they will share Azure VM details in Excel sheet with below columns.

[image: Excel sheet values]

we have to get VM Status details from all the subscriptions & ResourceGroup using the Powershell script.

Outuput:

[image]

I am able to perform for single RSG and VM values by using the below code

```css
$SubscriptionName = Get-AzSubscription -SubscriptionId $subscriptionId
$RG = "rgp-use2-prd-bioportalbiopeople1"
$RSGName = Get-AzResourceGroup -Name $RG
$VMs = Get-AzVM -Name "vmbppapiv1prd02" 
$VMState = (Get-AzVM -Name $VM -ResourceGroupName $RG -Status).Statuses
$vmOutput = $VMs | ForEach-Object {
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        "Resource Group Name" = $RSGName.ResourceGroupName
        "Subscription Name" = $SubscriptionName.Name
        "VM Name" = $_.Name
        "VM Type" = $_.StorageProfile.osDisk.osType
        "VM Statss" = ($VMState | where code -Like 'PowerState/*')[0].DisplayStatus
        
      }
}

$vmOutput | Format-Table -AutoSize 
$vmOutput | export-csv C:\Projects\data.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't test this myself, but you will have to create nested loops to get the details for all subscriptions and resourcegroups.

Something like this:

```
$subscriptions = Get-AzSubscription -TenantId "aaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaa"  # enter the tenant ID here
$VMs = Get-AzVM -Name "vmbppapiv1prd02"

$vmOutput = foreach ($vm in $VMs) {
    foreach ($subscription in $subscriptions) {
        Set-AzContext -SubscriptionId $subscription.Id
        (Get-AzResourceGroup).ResourceGroupName | ForEach-Object {
            $vmState = (Get-AzVM -Name $vm.Name -ResourceGroupName $_ -Status).Statuses
            [PSCustomObject]@{
                "Resource Group Name" = $_
                "Subscription Name"   = $Subscription.Name
                "VM Name"             = $vm.Name
                "VM Type"             = $vm.StorageProfile.osDisk.osType
                "VM Status"           = ($vmState | where code -Like 'PowerState/*')[0].DisplayStatus
            }
        }
    }
}

$vmOutput | Format-Table -AutoSize 
$vmOutput | Export-Csv -Path 'C:\Projects\data.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Get-AzVM : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'ResourceGroupName'. The argument is null or empty. Provide an argument that is not null or empty, and then try the command again.
At line:1 char:51
+ $vmState = (Get-AzVM -Name $vm -ResourceGroupName $_ -Status).Statuse ...
+                                                   ~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Get-AzVM], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationError,Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Compute.GetAzureVMCommand

Comment: @user2128849 `Get-AzVM -Name $vm` should have been `Get-AzVM -Name $vm.Name`. Fixed now